# Windows Server 2003 remote desktop crash

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

I have a trouble with RDP on Windows server 2003. When I start the system everything seems to work (3389 port is listening), I can connect with rdp client, just after login confirm the client exits and then the Remote Desktop stops (3389 is not listen anymore). Than if i try to reconnect by rdp client an error occurred before logon (something like server is not reachable).
Have you got some suggestions to solve this? Thanks

This is the event log:

```
Nome dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: svchost.exe_TermService, versione: 6.1.7600.16385, timestamp: 0x4a5bc3c1
Nome del modulo che ha generato l'errore: rdpcorekmts.dll, versione: 6.1.7600.16952, timestamp: 0x4f1f9e66
Codice eccezione: 0xc0000005
Offset errore 0x000000000000a793
ID processo che ha generato l'errore: 0xc14
Ora di avvio dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: 0x01cd64b312187aeb
Percorso dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
Percorso del modulo che ha generato l'errore: C:\Windows\system32\rdpcorekmts.dll
ID segnalazione: 793873de-d0a6-11e1-82ee-001a64d377ec
```

Comment: Please add at least logs (see trough eventlog) and an EXACT error message

Answer (score 0):

Check drivers, check hardware, install englich OS so that you don't go to an english speaking site with italian error messages.

Simple like that.

Likely either broken hardware or a bad driver somewhere.

Also helps to upgrad the OS to a more recent one ;)

Comment: Maybe you forget: check power cord... thank you for useful suggestions.

Comment: At least outside of italy the power cord is hardware ;)